# How do you get a pre-defined size/length of a variable in R?

Tags: r

For example: I create a new numeric vector or variable in my data with this

`newVector <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 8)`

I am looking for a simple function to get the pre-defined length of it which is `8` in this case,
not the number of digits in its numeric values.

Comment: If you have a vector of certain `length`, use `newVector <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = length(yourvec))`

Comment: `length(newVector)` will be 8. R doesn't have numeric types where you can specify the number of digits. You could `round()` a floating point value to a certain number of digits, but the bytes size of numeric values remains the same. I'm not quite sure what you are getting at here.